# Error when trying to read .csv files from Github

Tags: r, csv, ssl, github

I am trying to read a few csv files from Github into R using `import` function from package `rio` but getting an error which is displayed below.

```
Error in fread(input = file, sep = sep, sep2 = "auto", header = header,  : 
  The supplied 'sep' was not found on line 1. To read the file as a single character column set sep='\n'.
```

The code I have used is

```
import("https://raw.github.com/smbilal/SCC413/blob/master/HP.csv")
```

The file can be seen using the above URL and is a comma separated file but cannot seem to figure out what is the problem. I have tried other methods like "getURL" but that also ends up throwing a SSL error and the description is below.

```
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

Could it still be a problem with SSL that I cant seem to read the files using "import" or I am making some other mistake?

Comment: I get a "not found" with that URL. Are you sure your URL is correct?

Comment: I agree. If you take the "raw" out of the URL it works where as I was under the impression that raw will fetch the actual data. Do I need to check why the URL is not working with "raw"? I have tried import with "raw" and it is giving the same error.

Comment: The correct URL is https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smbilal/SCC413/master/HP.csv OR https://github.com/smbilal/SCC413/raw/master/HP.csv which redirects to the first URL.

Comment: Thanks Anand. So it was an error on getting the right URL. Appreciate your help.

Comment: And since it's a csv file you can simply run `read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smbilal/SCC413/master/HP.csv")`, you don't need an external package just for that.